Switchable power strip cannot be switched off
I had a power strip which could be turned on and off (to control the power of its plugs at once) by a single switch. One day, that switch stopped working: The power strip could not be switched off anymore. It would be clear to me if it could not be have been switched on anymore, but it was really always on.
Even while holding down the rock switch in off-position, its control light kept lit, and all attached devices kept powered. As soon as I released the switch, I jumped back to its on-position.
So, I bought a new switchable power strip and replaced the old one with it. It was working as expected for about 2 weeks, and then the same thing happened again: It's not possible to turn it off anymore. It's exactly the same behaviour.
One additional observation: The new power strip has two additional LEDs: One is lit if its internal fuse is good, and one if the ground is connected. The ground LED was never lit.
What is the reason for this phenomenon, and can it be solved?

Two options.
The switch is simply mechanically broken and stuck to on position. This has happened with cheap devices with cheap switches. The problem is that in such case the force applied to the switch contacts may be too weak if it does not work properly so the contacts may make poor contact with high contact resistance, causing heating up and melting of plastic around it or simply arcing over the contacts, which may be heard as sizzling and the devices on the strip may experience high surges and damage.
Second option is you have very high load (as in resistive) or very high inrush current (as in capacitive load) so the switch contacts may simply be welded together if they did not handle switching of the load or inrush current.
So you can't know if it was a poor quality device and you should get a new one under warranty, or it was not rated for your use case and your use damaged it. Buy a new one.
The ground LED being lit means you have no ground on your wall socket. If your socket is supposed to have ground, it is either broken or not even installed. To fix that you should call an electrician to see what the problem is and how to fix it.

Note that I said it were two power strips with the same issue. Inrush current in the moment it is turned on may be a good hint, because there are 3 laptop power adapters connected.

@rexkogitans And two power strips cannot fail with same problem? I've had many devices fail with same problem. Including power strips with a fault that switch does not turn them off.


What is the reason for this phenomenon

Under-rated components (switch) in the power strip relative to your loads.

can it be solved?

It depends on what you agree to consider it "solved". There are really only two things you can do:

Buy a good brand power strip. A Premium series (metal case) Tripp-Lite product should, I hope, be good enough.

Reduce the transient load that causes high inrush current and presumed switch contact welding. Having fewer "laptop-style" adapters plugged in at once may help with that. You could unplug them all and then plug them one-at-a-time.


If your loads are just extremely poorly behaved, you'd need to use a contactor to disconnect them, and use the switch just to control the contactor. Use a contactor rated for tungsten loads, which have very high inrush current as well. It may seem like swatting a fly with a cannon, but you probably won't ever have to think about that switching problem again.
